# Как изменить props внутри компонента

Tags: reactjs

Есть родительский компонент

```
<TagsSelect name="Tags" value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.onFormChange} />
```

Внутри него другой компонента

```
class TagsSelect extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const colors = ['orange', 'red', 'blue', 'purple'];

        return (
            <Multiselect
                value={this.props.value}
                data={colors}
                onChange={value => this.props.value = value}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'value' of object '#'

на строке `this.props.value = value;`

Вопрос в том как вернуть в value родительского элемента то что возвращается в `value` в `onChange`

Comment: Состояние компонента нужно хранить в `state`, а не в `props`. Либо сохранять в какое-то внешнее по отношению к компоненту хранилище и спускать в компонент через `props`.

Comment: передаешь функцию, в функцию значение, в компоненте верхнего уровня сработает метод, присвоишь значение.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TagsSelect extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const colors = ['orange', 'red', 'blue', 'purple'];

        onChangeHandler(val) {
          let value = val
          this.setState({value});
        }

        return (
            <Multiselect
                onChangeHandlerFunc={this.onChangeHandler}
                data={colors}
                onChange={value => this.props.onChangeHandlerFunc(value)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.